# Xcode if Expected Identifier Error

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I think I'm going myopic, what is wrong with this line?

```
if ([hour > hourSunrise] && [hour < hourSunset])
```

I get an `Identifier Error` on the last `]` and there is of course a `{` at the end of the line.
All the variables are `ints`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square brackets `[ ... ]` are used by Objective-C syntax for *method calls*, such as

```
[someObject doSomething];
```

(see ["Objects Send and Receive Messages"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW2)
in the "Programming with Objective-C" documentation for more information).

What you probably meant is

```
if ((hour > hourSunrise) && (hour < hourSunset)) ...
```

And in this particular case no parentheses are needed at all because `&&`
has a lower precedence than the comparison operators such as `<`:

```
if (hour > hourSunrise && hour < hourSunset) ...
```

Comment: Many thanks, I am slowly getting my head accustomed to the way that strings and numbers are dealt with differently in C.